# Run a docker image with java and python

Tags: python, spring-boot, docker

I have a spring boot app which I have dockerized using DockerFile
now my spring boot app also runs a python script for which I will need a python environment in the same docker image.
how do I modify my Dockerfile so that I achieve the above functionality?
Also please tell me what will be the python home in that case.
my DockerFile is as follows:

```
FROM openjdk:11
ADD target/python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
EXPOSE 9091
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: I think you have to create a custom image, install python, open jdk one by one and run it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending if you need python 2 or 3 ? 
Python 2.7.13 is by default in the image. So you will be able to use it.
If you need python3 you will have to create a custom Docker Image:

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 9091
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3
ADD target/python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "python-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Hope it helps.